# React Admin parseResponse doesn't trigger when query returns error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-admin

I'm using React Admin and ra-data-graphQl, when I update something in my UserEdit component all works perfect, BUT, when I need to handle the error message from the API, I don't know where catch it.

This is my Update query:

```
case 'UPDATE': {
  const updateParams = { ...params };

  return {
    query: gql`mutation updateUser($id: ID!, $data: UpdateUser!) {
                    data: updateUser(id: $id,input:$data) {
                        ${buildFieldsGraphQL(updateFields)}
                    }
                }`,

    variables: {
      ...updateParams,
      id: updateParams.data.uuid,
      data: {
        ...updateParams.data,
      },
    },
    parseResponse: (response) => {
      console.log('tr response: ', response);
    },
  };
}
```

When the API returns an error, it never reach the console.log.

I was searching a list with options here (https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-graphql#options) searching something like "parseError", but I did not find nothing similar.

I need to catch the error and show a message in the UserEdit form.

Reading the link that I share in this post, it say this:

> but must return an object matching the options of the ApolloClient query method with an additional parseResponse function.

I understand that I should go to the link in the word "query" and check if there is something like "parserError", but the link is broken:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/reference/index.html#ApolloClient.query

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, its easier. By adding the [onFailure](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#onfailure) function I can handle the error.